# Merging cv::Mat horizontally

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu

I want to merge a few `cv::Mat`, when I use `mat1.push_back(mat2)` it add `mat2` to the end of `mat1` vertically , is there a way to do this horizontally?
The only other option I can think of is making every `cv::Mat` into a `cv::RotatedRect`, rotate it, creating a new `Mat`, merging, rotating everything in the end in the same way, but it sound pointlessly long if there is another way

Answer (score 21):

Take a look at [hconcat](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gaab5ceee39e0580f879df645a872c6bf7) and [vconcat](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga744f53b69f6e4f12156cdde4e76aed27).

usage:

```
Mat M1,M2,HM,VM;
// M1 and M2 - source matrices
// HM,VM - results matrices
 ...

 hconcat(M1,M2,HM); // horizontal concatenation
 vconcat(M1,M2,VM); // vertical   concatenation
```

Take care, these methods are not documented.

Comment: Minor typo in the comment on line 3 (HM and VM instead of MH and MV) but doesn't affect the results :)

Comment: Note that these methods are now documented: [hconcat](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gaf9771c991763233866bf76b5b5d1776f) and [vconcat](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga744f53b69f6e4f12156cdde4e76aed27).

Comment: It mentioned in answer.

Comment: I tried hconcat with different number of rows it crashes. Works only if number of rows are same. but works fine if number of cols are different

Comment: Yes that's correct and can't be else. You can't combine horizontally matrices with different number of rows. As you can't combine vertically matrices with different number of cols.

Answer (score 2):

There is a very simple way of displaying two images side by side. The following function can be used which is provided by opencv.

```
Mat image1, image2;
hconcat(image1,image2,image1);//Syntax->
hconcat(source1,source2,destination);
```

This function can also be used to copy a set of columns from an image to another image.

```
Mat image;
Mat columns=image.colRange(20,30);
hconcat(image,columns,image);
```