# How to concatenate smaller matrices or vectors to form a larger one OpenCV c++ cv::Matx

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, vector, concatenation

Suppose you have 3 5-vectors and you want to fill an 15-vector with them. (If I know how to do this I will know how to work with cv::Matx matrices too)

```
int const DIM = 5;
int const STS = 15;
typedef cv::Matx<double, DIM,1>    VecDim;
typedef cv::Matx<double, STS,1>    VecSts;
.
.
.
VecDim xSt, ySt, wSt;

Then some process occur and their values will be set.
```

Is there any way in OpenCV 3.1 to do:

```
VecSts allVals;
allVals << xSt, ySt, wSt;
```

Or the only "elegant" way ( because it is a bit better than filling `Vec15` element by element) it is a for loop as follows?

```
for(int id = 0; id < DIM; ++id)
{
   allVals(id,0)       = xSt(id,0);
   allVals(id+DIM,0)   = ySt(id,0);
   allVals(id+2*DIM,0) = wSt(id,0);
}
```

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078875/merging-cvmat-horizontally

Comment: @MD.NazmulKibria Good call. Note that those methods are now documented.