# What's an efficient way to prepend multiple rows to Open CV cv::Mat in C++?

Tags: c++, opencv

So to append rows to a cv:Mat I can do something like this:

```
Mat a(Mat::ones(2000, 3000, CV_32FC(5)));
Mat padding(Mat::zeros(2000, 3000, CV_32FC(5)));
a.push_back(padding);
```

What's the performance-efficient way to prepend rows to a? One suggestion is to use cv::vconcat but I don't think vconcat is efficient.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merging cv::Mat horizontally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078875/merging-cvmat-horizontally)

Comment: Use vconcat ...