# Displaying 2 Camera Feeds Into One Window With OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to display 2 camera feeds into a single window using openCV/c++.

The following code opens two camera windows.  How can I combine them together?

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main()
{
    //initialize and allocate memory to load the video stream from camera 
    cv::VideoCapture camera0(0);
    cv::VideoCapture camera1(1);

    if( !camera0.isOpened() ) return 1;
    if( !camera1.isOpened() ) return 1;

    while(true) {
        //grab and retrieve each frames of the video sequentially 
        cv::Mat3b frame0;
        camera0 >> frame0;
        cv::Mat3b frame1;
        camera1 >> frame1;

        cv::imshow("Video0", frame0);
        cv::imshow("Video1", frame1);

        //wait for 40 milliseconds
        int c = cvWaitKey(40);

        //exit the loop if user press "Esc" key  (ASCII value of "Esc" is 27) 
        if(27 == char(c)) break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do the following:

Step 1: Resize both frames to have the same size

Step 2: Concatenate both frames into one

Step 3: Output(imshow) the concatenated frame

Assuming both frames are of same shape:

```
cv::Mat3b frame0;
camera0 >> frame0;
cv::Mat3b frame1;
camera1 >> frame1;
cv::Mat3b combine;
hconcat(frame0,frame1,combine);
cv::imshow("Videos0and1", combine);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Unless displaying them with something other than OpenCV, you have to combine them into one Image.

[Merging cv::Mat horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078875/merging-cvmat-horizontally)