# How to concatenate matrices along z axis using opencv

Tags: opencv, c++11, opencv3.0

How to concatenate P

> M*N

matrices to get a

> M* N* P

matrix ?

Comment: So you mean like extra channels? Maybe is [merge](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#merge) what you are looking for

Comment: take a look at vconcat and hconcat https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga744f53b69f6e4f12156cdde4e76aed27 pretty much the same question here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078875/merging-cvmat-horizontally